# What does the error message "We don't have any refiners to show you" mean?

Tags: search, error

What does the error message "We don't have any refiners to show you" mean in the context of a new SharePoint 2013 site built on the enterprise search template?

Comment: Please provide more details. For example, what were you doing when you received the error? Are there notable messages in the logs (i.e. ULS or Windows eventlogs)? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I was establishing the new SharePoint site collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be many other reasons this is one of those. 
This is due to the refinement web part is not added on search page or settings are not configured properly.

You can check the detailed steps to resolve the issue it this is the reason :
http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.in/2014/03/we-dont-have-any-refiners-to-show-you.html

Comment: This helps a whole lot!

Comment: You can mark this as answer if it helps you. Thanks!!!

Comment: sorry to be such a newbie - but how do I do that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow